# Magento GO Bundled Product Page switch off single button

Tags: javascript, html, css, magento

After much work I have managed to move all the information from the Customization page on a Bundled Product to the front page.  I now want to hide the buttons that direct the user to the customization page.  Both buttons however use the save class name.

There are two separate buttons on this page : I need to hide the first button

Button 1 which is:

```
<div class=“product-shop”>
  <div class’Product-main-info”>
    <div>
      <button class="button btn-cart" type="button" onclick="Enterprise.Bundle.start();">
        <span>
          <span>Customize and Add to Cart</span>
        </span>
      </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Button 2 is:

```
<div class="add-to-cart">
   <label for="qty">Qty:</label>
   <input id="qty" class="input-text qty" type="text" title="Qty" value="1" maxlength="12" name="qty">
     <button class="button btn-cart" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)" title="Buy Now" type="button">
       <span>
         <span>Buy Now</span>
       </span>
     </button>
</div>
```

I have tried hiding the button using CSS however have only been able to switch both buttons off.  This the last step in a long Magento GO customization project. Any help much appreciated.

Regards

Mark

Comment: Sorry problem posting code for second button

Comment: You can post code blocks by indenting your code by four spaces. There is a nice button in the editor to do this for you. (Don't use blockquotes i.e. `>`.)